# How to concatenate strings in an array of array with Ramda.js

Tags: ramda.js

Given a 2d matrix of strings, I would like to concatenate the elements in the sublists based on their position.

e.g. Given this data structure as input:

```
[['x','y' ,'z'],['A', 'B', 'C'], ['a', 'b', 'c']]
```

The algorithm would produce the output:

```
['xAa', 'yBb', 'zCc']
```

I tried `R.transpose`, but it gets me `[['x','A','a'], ['y', 'B', 'b'], ['z', 'C', 'c']]`, however I couldn't find a way to concatenate the nested strings.

I also tried `R.zipWith`, but it doesn't look ideal since `R.zipWith` takes only two arguments so that I need to apply it twice to get the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You weren't that far off I think.

With `transpose` you managed to get this:

```
[['x','A','a'], ['y', 'B', 'b'], ['z', 'C', 'c']]
```

Then you just need to map over this array of arrays and join each of them.

e.g.

```js
const {compose, map, join, transpose } = R
const concat_arr = compose(map(join("")), transpose);
const result = concat_arr([['x','y' ,'z'],['A', 'B', 'C'], ['a', 'b', 'c']]);
console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.1/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

Where `compose`, `map`, `join` and `transpose` are all Ramda functions.

1. The initial input goes to `transpose`
2. The result of `transpose(arr)` is given to `map(join(""))` which applies `join("")` to all sub arrays